# Access Exchange mailbox information

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to create an external API for managing mailboxes (as well as certain other things) on an Exchange server.

I'm starting small - so first I want to be able to manage Exchange resources (which are basically mailboxes with a property flag set).

The EWS service doesn't offer the functionality I need, so I'm looking for other options.

PowerShell can perform basic CRUD operations on mailboxes, HOWEVER I couldn't get it to retrieve additional mailbox information (resources can have additional contact information like location, phone number, etc. which I would also like to retrieve / set).

I could retrieve these values by accessing the LDAP object, but this seems wrong because I now have to use two separate technologies - I wonder if there's a better way to do this. After all, I find it hard to believe that the ECP (graphical GUI web panel for managing Exchange) accesses LDAP directly.

Is there some kind of managed API (even if it can be used on the same server as Exchange only) which would allow me to manipulate the mailboxes and all things related (delegates, auto-acceptance rules, contact information, etc.)?

EDIT: I was able to get the additional information using `Get-Recipient` command, however there's no apparent way to SET these properties (outside of changing the LDAP entries).

Comment: In fact, you should use only LDAP to retrieve these properties. Exchange enhances AD schema for its needs, but common attributes are not replicated to Exchnge mailbox instances themselves. And yes, EMC does query LDAP, more, it changes attributes in LDAP if you adjust the mailbox. Also, Exchange has a metric ton of cmdlets to manage Exchange data, so you might first look there for options.

Comment: @Vesper Thanks. I was hoping there's a more centralized way of doing things...

Comment: Exchange sits on top of LDAP but think of it more as LDAP is the directory database for exchange.  All the contact, mailbox, resources they are all LDAP objects so you are better off querying LDAP for that info.